# Restsharp and Xamarin Cycle 7 not connecting

Tags: ios, xamarin, restsharp

Since updating to Xamarin ios cycle 7, whenever I try to connect to my server the header which i receive is always:

```
{Connection=close&Host=172.16.101.12&User-Agent=Manager%25202%2f1.0+CFNetwork%2f758.4.3+Darwin%2f15.5.0}
```

However it should have an authorisation key within it, - prior to updating this always worked.

```cs
var client = new RestClient(EndPoint);
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(UserName, Password);
return client;
```

Does anyone know why I am no longer receiving an Authorisation header at he other end - and for that matter, why ios now always seems to want to close the connection?

(I am currently using Restsharp 105.2.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all down to ios wanting to make sure that we are running over a secure connection, for my dev environment, i am not working over an HTTPS connection, therefore I have had to add in some bits and pieces into the info.plist.  For more information please read up here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/platform_features/introduction_to_ios9/ats/

Unfortunately I suffered from my program not being rebuilt properly, so the first time I tried this (and a few more) it was not picking up this setting, therefore once you have added in the keys, make sure you clean and then build!

- As another point, I found that it did not work with ip address, it has to be an actual domain name.